# Is there a way to setup an e-mail account through a third party android app

Tags: android, email, installation

I am trying to make an Android app that will ask a user to enter his e-mail address and  password for it, and I want to be able to launch the default Android e-mail app and setup this e-mail in the native e-mail app. If this is not possible however, could you please point me to a solution which is similar to this. My main idea is to setup an e-mail account without much hassle and no need to create a custom UI for it, that's why I want to use the native app if possible.